# Can I move updates from games to an HDD?

Tags: ps4

I own the first model of the PlayStation 4 console and was wondering, with the new updates, can I move the update data of my games (like *Fallout 4* whose updates are like 44 GB or *FFXV*, actually more than 60 GB) into an external HDD connected and play the games as I normally do?

It is possible? I don't want to change the internal HDD.

Also, will my games/saves be altered if I do this?

Comment: I would think that this is unfortunately not possible.  I'm not positive, but if I had to guess, when you download an update, it gets applied to the game files, and once its complete, the data downloaded for the update is removed to free up the space.

Comment: You could always install the games on the external HDD as the update files will be wherever you install the game but I don't know if that would count as a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not possible, because you can't simply separate an update file from the game itself on a PS4. As Timmy Jim mentioned in the comments, these update files you download and install aren't simply left on your PS4. They either replace files for the game or are added to it (in the instance they're entirely new).

A [helpful Q&A over from GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/39933/how-do-patches-in-games-work) explains how updates work quite nicely:

> However, most patching systems in the wild take the simplest route: they just package files that have changed - they don't attempt to only package changes within those files (probably for good reason, most game content is compressed already and creating patches against high entropy or compressed data won't work at all).